# Submitting ajax form displays all php isset statements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using following code to send the form through ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#update-settings").submit(function(e) {

        var url = "files/jquery-pages/page_jquery_settings.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $("#update-settings").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#success-settings").hide().html(data).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });

});
</script>

<div id="success-settings"></div>
```

and this is working fine so far.

My php page is loking like this:

```
<?php               
    if(isset($_POST['change_password']) == $settings_btn_change_password) 
    {       
        echo "The password has been changed";   
    }

    if(isset($_POST['update_email']) == $settings_btn_update_email) 
    {       
        echo "This is email update";
    }
?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="update-settings" id="update-settings">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $settings_btn_change_password;?>" name="change_password" class="button_blue_standard pull-right">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $settings_btn_update_email;?>" name="update_email" class="button_blue_standard pull-right">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is when i hit Submit button change_password example it´s displaying both "The password has been changed" and "This is email update".

I just want to show "The password has been changed" if I have hit that button.

Any ideas why?

Cheerz :)

Comment: I think problem is on your HTML form button change_password and update_email value, maybe they always have value when submitting, put more your HTML code please.

Comment: try using `!empty($_POST['change_password'])` only in condition

Comment: Have you define those `$settings_btn_*` vars in `files/jquery-pages/page_jquery_settings.php` file?

Comment: Yes they have been added there as well

Answer (score 0):

`isset` will not work with `==`. So use like this.

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['change_password'])) 
    {    
        echo "The password has been changed";
    }

    if(isset($_POST['update_email'])) 
    {  
        echo "This is email update";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Using `&&` might be better in my view.

Comment: If you use `&&` It will show the error, if it `isset($_POST['change_password'])` condition false.

Comment: Trying to use this code, but unfortunately nothing is happening at all :S im not getting anything displayed now.

Comment: Post your html form in question

Comment: You don't want the inner condition. now i modified the code, use like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116251/discussion-between-mensur-and-mani).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
   if((isset($_POST['change_password'])) && ($settings_btn_change_password==$_POST['change_password'])) 
    {  
        echo "The password has been changed";
    }
    if((isset($_POST['update_email'])) && ($settings_btn_update_email==$_POST['update_email'])) 
    {  
        echo "This is email update";
    }
?>
```

i hope it will be helpful

Comment: This one is not working at all. not getting any results.

Answer (score 0):

Please use 'exit;' after every echo statement. So it should be like this :-

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['change_password']) == $settings_btn_change_password) 
    {       
        echo "The password has been changed";
        exit;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['update_email']) == $settings_btn_update_email) 
    {       
        echo "This is email update";
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, 

This one is displaying only first isset. If I click on the second button it still shows the results of first isset.

Comment: please check the values of $settings_btn_update_email and $settings_btn_change_password should not be like 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm at work so i don't have time to test this but try:

```
if(isset($_POST['change_password']) && $_POST['change_password'] == $settings_btn_change_password) {
    echo "The password has been changed";
    exit();
} else if(isset($_POST['update_email']) && $_POST['update_email'] == $settings_btn_update_email) {
    echo "This is an email update";
    exit();
} else {
    echo "Action not successfully carried out, try again";
    error_log("There's an issue here, check it out"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.. 
The output is: Action not successfully carried out, try again

Comment: Okay, give me a minute to test